# Variables - Other scripts - jQuery

Tags: jquery

Already, I'm newer on jQuery language.

So, this is my question :
How can i use a variable from a first script to another script in jQuery ?

The script 1 retrieve item selected from dropdown list :

**Script 1 :**

```
<script>
        $('#ERDF').change(function codeterdf() 
      {
        var codet_erdf = $('#ERDF option:selected').first().attr('value');

    // Display on input named "pu"
    // $('#pu').val(codet_erdf);

    });
</script>
```

And my second script, it will be to check if var "codet_erdf" is defined or not with "undefined".
*PS : The second script will be execute only when the button is clicked.*

**Script 2 :**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            if (typeof codet_erdf == 'undefined') {
                $("p").text("Codet ERDF non choisi");
            }
            else
            {
                $("p").val(codet_erdf);
            }
        }
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: This will not work unless script 1 is placed AFTER the #ERDF object OR wrapped in `$(function() {... });` too. Also if the select is not `multiple` then the code could be written as `var codet_erdf = $('#ERDF').val();`

Comment: Why don't get the selected item when button is clicked ?

Comment: make this variable `codet_erdf` global and it should work.

Comment: To follow up @HarryBomrah comment - put `var codet_erdf` outside the `$('#ERD')` block and inside the block remove the 'var' (just `codet_erdf=`)

Comment: @freedomn-m Without "var", my variable will be global?

Comment: I said add a var outside - that defines it as global, then inside you're using the global that's already been defined.   But yes, without var it will be global, but it's not recommended as it looks like a mistake/bug.

Comment: @HareshVidja has provided a realisation for you of what I said above

Comment: Always don't work. Any others solutions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In script-1 you have to declare global variable(outside of function).

**Script-1**

```
<script>
var codet_erdf='';
  $('#ERDF').change(function codeterdf() {
    codet_erdf = $('#ERDF option:selected').first().attr('value');

// Display on input named "pu"
// $('#pu').val(codet_erdf);

});
</script>`
```

**Script-2**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            if (codet_erdf == '') {
                $("p").text("Codet ERDF non choisi");
            }
            else
            {
                $("p").val(codet_erdf);
            }
        }
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: How can retrieve the var for use it on SQL request please?

Comment: I didn't get you prpperly, but I assume you want to send value of this variable to SQL... you can send it to ajax request and update it in SQL by server side scripting

Comment: I share a JSfidlle @Haresh Vidja

Comment: Sorry In this way its not possible.. you have to make server side script in other file and call it by ajax and pass parameter value and field name through post method in ajax and then write your code of update value in that script..

Comment: You have to understand execution way of server side script and client/broweser script first...

Comment: Yes sorry .. I have difficulty for this because I learn several language for my job.. Sorry. I saw than he need to use AJAX right?

Answer (score 0):

The way to go here is to get the value *only when you need it*.

ie:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var cdet_erdf = $('#ERDF').val();
        if (cdet_erdf === "") {
            $("p").text("Codet ERDF non choisi");
        }
        else
        {
            $("p").text(codet_erdf);
            // or
            $("p").text($("#ERDF").text());
        }
    }
};
```

in this case, your default/first option under the select would not have a value, which will give `""`, eg:

```
<select>
    <option>Please select...</option>
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    ....
```

Comment: I want use var outside script tag. How please? @freedomn-m

Comment: @McNavy you should ask a new question, it's not related to this question.